# Get parameter from money.yandex.ru

Tags: node.js, express, request

I use node.js in my project. I need get parameter from remote server. It send me data with POST method. I can dump value with `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)`. But I can't assign this value to a node variable.

Output console.log:

```
{"test_notification":"true","sender":"41001000040","amount":"675.96","operation_id":"test-notification","sha1_hash":"bff14842b2411a237f8303154390769f7cda7ab4","notification_type":"p2p-incoming","codepro":"false","label":"","datetime":"2014-10-19T08:39:03Z","currency":"643"}
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Could you post the code where you "assign this value to a node variable"?

Comment: i resolve this problem. Thx.